# How to assign a total to a name in Java

Tags: java

I am using a switch statement to choose 5 products.  I want to assign the total to a name I can add up

```
double total;
(prod1 * 12.80) = total1
```

problem is it says "total" is not initalized

I got `prod1 * 12.80` to work, but I need the total of that computation to add to a statement like

```
System.out.println("grand total = " +  total1 + total2 + " = " ;
```

All,

Here is the first part of my code switch.  I have 4 more cases to the switch that all have totals.  I need all these totals from each switch to be added up for a grand total.

```
public class test 
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
//declare a scanner for user Input 
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
int choice; 
double prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4,prod5; 
double lineCost1 = 2.98;
double lineCost2 = 4.50;
double total1 = prod1 * lineCost1; // This is a intial set valueforthe   Grand total   but can't get it to work 

 
do 
{ 
//display our menu 
System.out.println("***ProductSelection***\n"); 
System.out.println("Please Select a Product Number from 1-5\n"); 
System.out.println("To quit the Program Please enter 6."); 
System.out.println("*********************"); 
System.out.println("Please enter your choice:"); 

//get user input 
choice = userInput.nextInt(); 

//switch the choice from user 
  switch(choice) 

 { 

 case 1://Product 1 
 System.out.println("Product 1"); 
 System.out.println("Please enter the Quantity you want:"); 
 prod1 = userInput.nextInt(); 
 System.out.println("Quantity = " +  prod1 + " at a Line Cost of " +"$"+ 2.98 + " = " +"$"+ (total1)); 
 break;
```

THIS is THE ERROR I GET
: variable prod1 might not have been initialized
double total1 = prod1 * lineCost1; // This is a intial set valueforthe   Grand total but can't get it to work
^
1 error

Comment: Please please please get yourself an introductory book on Java...

Comment: I'm guessing you're new to programming.  In many programming languages, including Java, assignments take the form `answer = expression`.  For example, `int x = 1 + 1;`.  Also, Java (like the C family of languages) offers a convenience operator for things like this.  Once you have your running total, you can say `total += 42;`, which is the equivalent of saying `total = total + 42`.

Comment: Could you post all of the applicable classes and I will help you out.

Comment: Also, notice that I used the same variable (`total`) twice in my previous comment.  Java will execute the entire expression first (i.e., `total + 42`) before assigning it to the `total` variable, so it would read "the new value of total becomes the old value of total plus 42".

Comment: To add to what Oli said above -- **and** read it!

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with the following?  Why do you want to write your expression backwards?

```
double total = prod1 * 12.8;
```